# .net dll class member not showing

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I've been working with c++ for little over 10 years now, and I have situation where I have to develop vb.net dll for Excel vba, so I have been teaching myself vb.net - it's bit, I must say, curious language.
Now here is problem that I have.  I have compiled a small vb.net code, and I was able to reference through Excel vba.  However, when I wrote vba and tried to test it, I get "#value" error from Excel.
Here is the codes.

[vb.net]

```
Public Class myDll
   Public Sub WriteSomething()
       MsgBox("Hello, World")
   End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the vba side.

```
Public Function TestingDll() As Integer
   Dim x As New DLLTest.myDll
   x.WriteSomething()
   TestingDll 0
End Function
```

Now I checked with "Object Browser", and it seems like Excel does not see any member of class.  Now I have looked through to see if I can find any solution.  And mostly what I found are related to GUID.  Does anyone has better idea than using GUID?  I don't want to use GUID because I have never used it before.

Comment: Your last line should be `TestingDll =0`   http://csharphelper.com/blog/2013/10/make-a-c-dll-and-use-it-from-excel-vba-code/

Comment: You don't need to use VB.Net.  If you'd prefer you can use C#.

Comment: The comment from @Nathan_Sav is the reason for your #value error. Is the code you've listed as "the vba side" in a module in an Excel file? If so, you should be able to see the function TestDll when you click on the "fx" symbol to insert a function in a formula for a worksheet cell, when you select "user defined functions". Is that good enough?  Can you see the class myDll in the object browser?

Comment: My bad.  Yes.  It has been written in "TestingDll = 0" - it's my mistype.  And Yes.  It is in "module".  And Excel also lists the function, too.  And "Object Browser" sees the class but not class members including methods.

Answer (score 0):

The setting on VS2019 was set as "Any CPU" for target machines.  After changing it to "64 bit" - since the target Excel was 64 bit - it works like charm.